# How do I end function when X

Tags: postgresql, insert, performance, plpgsql, set-returning-functions, postgresql-performance

so my function looks like this:

```
create or replace function insert_stuff(a1 text, a2 text, a3 int)
returns table (id_i int, id_j int) as
$$ begin return query
with 
i1(id1) as select insert_here(a1,a2),
i2(id2) as select insert_there(a3,a2),
select id1,id2 from i1,i2;
end; $$
```

I need the function to check if `a1||a2 in table_1.a12` before running the inserts and if it is in skip that insert and move onto the next.

I tried:

```
create or replace function insert_stuff(a1 text, a2 text, a3 int)
returns table (id_i int, id_j int) as
$$ begin return query
with 
i1(id1) as select insert_here(a1,a2),
i2(id2) as select insert_there(a3,a2),
select id1,id2 from i1,i2;
exception when select (select a1||a2) in (select a12 from table_1) then
end; $$
```

but this just causes the query to stall out

Comment: Please clarify: `and if it is in skip that insert and move onto the next.` And always declare your version of Postgres. Also relevant: how many rows can each nested function return? (0-n?)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.insert_stuff(_a1 text, _a2 text, _a3 int)
  RETURNS TABLE (id_i int, id_j int) AS
$func$
BEGIN 
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM table_1 WHERE a12 = _a1||a2) THEN  -- see below
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT -1, NULL;
      -- RAISE EXCEPTION 'Some informative msg here'  -- alternative?
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT insert_here(_a1, _a2)
           , insert_there(_a3, _a2);
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the clearer (and faster) `IF EXISTS`. See:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists/11892796#11892796)

Either variant might fail "unexpectedly" if either input parameter or the column `a12` can be NULL! You would have to define desired behavior.

***Subtle difference:*** Since I replaced your CTE construct with a simple `SELECT`, the function *always* returns at least one now, even if either nested function (`insert_here()` or `insert_there()`) returns *no row*. [Your version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217289/3684) would return *nothing* in this case, which may be a sneaky bug if either of the nested functions *can* return no row.

I am assuming Postgres 10 or later (you didn't declare). Else, depending on the undeclared nature of the nested functions, you might need to consider:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Answer (score 0):

one solution I have found :

```
create or replace function insert_stuff(a1 text, a2 text, a3 int)
returns table (id_i int, id_j int) as
$$ begin 
if (select (select a1||a2) in (select a12 from table_1)) then
return query select -1;
else
return query
with 
i1(id1) as select insert_here(a1,a2),
i2(id2) as select insert_there(a3,a2),
select id1,id2 from i1,i2;
end if;
end; $$
```

side note : this output is a record of insert, and when it errors it gives guidance for entries that need the human touch because they require a complex revision to match data we need in the database